# connecting the setInputStream and setOutputStream of the JSch to jTextField's

Tags: shell, connection, jsch

I am new to java and i need help.
I use the jsch libraries to create a SHH connection to a remote linux machine. In the next code, given from a tutorial of the JSCH creator, you can see it is implemented shell communication, it is a direct communication from a cmd window. You enter a command from the cmd window and you get aback the results in the cmd window.

```
String user = "username";
String host = "hostname";

session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
String passwd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter password");
session.setPassword(passwd);
Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");
session.connect();
channel.setInputStream(System.in);
channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
```

How i can connect the next two lines to jTextField1 and jTextField2. To give an example i want to sen the command from the jTextField1 and to get the results from the jTextField2.

```
channel.setInputStream(System.in);
channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
```

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2):

Instead of System.in you can give your desired stream .For example

```
String ls = "ls \n"; // here i am passing a string to stream, you  can pass as you desire
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(ls.getBytes("UTF-8"));
channel2.setInputStream(in);//you passed the string as input 


ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(out);
channel2.setOutputStream(ps);
String result = out.toString();//here we get output to a string which you can add to your file.
```

This is one option There may be better ways.